# Sql syntax to insert every thousandth positive integer, starting from 1 and up until 1 million?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
  thousand INT(10) UNSIGNED,
  UNIQUE(thousand)
);
```

Is there sql syntax I can use to insert every thousandth positive integer, starting from 1 and up until 1 million?  I can achieve this in php, but I was wondering if this was possible without using a stored procedure.

```
thousand
1
1001
2001
3001
4001
...
998001
999001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into dummy
   ( thousand )
select
     PreQuery.thousand 
  from
    (  select
             @sqlvar thousand,
             @sqlvar := @sqlvar + 1000
          from
             AnyTableWithAtLeast1000Records,
             ( select @sqlvar := 1 ) sqlvars
          limit 1000 ) PreQuery
```

You can insert from a select statement.  Using MySQL Variables, start with 1.  Then, join to ANY table in your system that may have 1000 (or more) records just to generate a row.  Even though not getting any actual column from such table, we just need it for the record position.  Then the @sqlvar starts at 1 and is returned in column named thousand.  Then, immediately add 1000 to it for the next record in the "AnyTable..."

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, mysql doesn't support this with any special SQL function.

You have to populate a table, which isn't such a big deal - it would only be 1000 rows.
You can also hack together a temporary table with unions, but that's hardly elegant - might as well use a table.

Other databases *do* support it, eg with postgres' `generate_series()` function, but that is little consolation.

As a side note, I often find it handy to have a table populated with consecutive numbers from `1` up to a large numebr for just such as occasion, and I would just `select 1000 * num from numbers where num <= 1000`.

Comment: Well, it's actually quite possible, have a look at the answers.

Comment: @SergeBelov yes... I meant "supported natively with a dedicated function for this purpose". I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For a *one statement query*, i.e. without introducing any additional tables and supporting statement, I'd use this approach in 'pseudo' SQL:

```
SELECT (D1.Digit + D2.Digit + D3.Digit)* 1000 + 1
FROM  
(
    SELECT 0 AS Digit UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
) AS D1
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Digit UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 40 UNION ALL
    SELECT 50 UNION ALL
    SELECT 60 UNION ALL
    SELECT 70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 80 UNION ALL
    SELECT 90
) AS D2
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Digit UNION ALL
    SELECT 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT 500 UNION ALL
    SELECT 600 UNION ALL
    SELECT 700 UNION ALL
    SELECT 800 UNION ALL
    SELECT 900
) AS D3
WHERE ((D1.Digit + D2.Digit + D3.Digit)* 1000 + 1) < 1000000
```

I'm not 100% sure but it should run fine in mysql or perhaps require some minor change.

If you're able to reuse parts of the query, it becomes much prettier, for example in SQL Server, I'd write it as follows:

```
WITH Digits AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Digit UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
)
SELECT (D1.Digit + D2.Digit + D3.Digit)* 1000 + 1
FROM (SELECT Digit FROM Digits) AS D1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Digit * 10 AS Digit FROM Digits) AS D2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Digit * 100 AS Digit FROM Digits) AS D3
WHERE ((D1.Digit + D2.Digit + D3.Digit)* 1000 + 1) < 1000000
```

Keep an eye on where multiplication happens, it might be more efficient to multiply in sub-queries, rather than in the resulting expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick, that I usually use for those sort of problems, similar to @sergeBelov solution:

Create an anchor table, a temp table, and fill it with values from 0 to 9, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (Digit int);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Then you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO dummy(thousand)
SELECT 1 + (id - 1) * 1000 AS n
FROM
(
  SELECT t3.digit * 100 + t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1  AS id
  FROM         TEMP AS t1
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t3
) t;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f91e2/1)

### How does this work?

The sequence numbers(`1, 1001, 2001, ... , 998001, 999001`) 1000 terms, that you are looking for, is what they called [**Arithmetic progression**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), and in your case the `nth` term of the sequence (`an`) is given by:

```
A + (n - 1) * d
In you sequence: a = 1, d = 1000
```

Where `A` is the first term of the sequence, n is the term and d is the difference between each two terms(it is the same for each two successive terms).

The subquery:

```
  SELECT t3.digit * 100 + t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1  AS id
  FROM         TEMP AS t1
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t3;
```

Will generate a list of numbers from 1 to 1000(the total number of terms in your sequence), after that we got each term in the sequence from these number by `1 + (id - 1) * 1000` in the outer select.